# Can I use a USB headset with my iPad's camera connection kit?

Tags: ipad, usb, headphones, camera

I know the camera connection kit can be used with USB microphones, but I'm wondering if USB headsets will work as well — both the speakers and the microphone — and whether this requires special applications (as with a MIDI USB device) or if they work natively with all audio apps?

Comment: @GraemeHutchison Oooh, good catch, thanks for reminding me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](http://tidbits.com/article/11221) and other articles, **yes,** it does work! (And it functions just like any other audio input/output device — with any application that supports audio in/out.)